# Show that $\mathbb{Z}_3(a)$ is a splitting field of the polynomial

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, irreducible-polynomials, splitting-field

We consider the polynomial $f(x)=x^2+1 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.

We symbolize as $a$ a root of $f(x)$ in an algebraic closure $\overline{\mathbb{Z}}_3$ of $\mathbb{Z}_3$.

Show that $\mathbb{Z}_3(a)$ is a splitting field of the polynomial $x^4+x^3+x+2 \in \mathbb{Z}_3[x]$.

I have done the following:

$a$ is a root of $f(x): a^2-1=0\Rightarrow a^2=1$

$x^4+x^3+x+2=x^2x^2+xx^2+x+2$

Setting $x=a$ we hav3 that:

$a^2a^2+aa^2+a+2=1+a+a+2=2a+3$

Does this mean that $a$ ios not a root of $x^4+x^3+x+2$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** Note that $x^4+x^3+x+2=(x^2+1)(x^2+x+2)$ and $(a+1)^2+(a+1)+2=0$.

Comment: It is $x^4+x^3+x+2$. Then we have that $$x^4+x^3+x+2=(x^2+1)(x^2+x-1)+1$$ We have that $a$ is a root of $x^2+1=0$. At $x=a$ we have that $a^4+a^3+a+2=(a^2+1)(a^2+a-1)+1=0+1=1$, right??

Comment: @MaryStar I just had a typo, my factorization is correct and yours is wrong. Check your calculations.

Comment: Oh, yes your factorization is correct!! Could you explain me how you get to the relation $(a+1)^2+(a+1)+2=0$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar To be honest it was just luck. You should know by now that $\mathbb Z_3(a)=\{\alpha a+\beta\colon \alpha, \beta \in \mathbb Z_3\}$. So I wanted to check if $x^2+x+2$ had any roots in $\mathbb Z_3(a)$ and luckily the first one I tried was one such root. You just have a few of them to try anyway, so this is something that can easily be done without luck.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you very much!!! :-)

Comment: I am looking again at this exercise and I got stuck... Is $\{\alpha a+\beta : \alpha , \beta \in \mathbb{Z}_3\}$ the definition of $\mathbb{Z}_3(a)$ ??

Comment: @MaryStar In general, if $\alpha$ is the root of an irreducible polynomial in $\mathbb F[x]$ of degreee $n$, then $\mathbb F(\alpha)=\{p(\alpha)\colon p(x)\in \mathbb F[x]\land \deg {p(x)}\leq n-1\}$. The equality follows, but it's not a definition. The exact definition varies, but you can just assume $\mathbb F(\alpha)$ is the smallest field containing $\mathbb F\cup \{\alpha\}$.

Comment: Ok... Thank you!!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar You're welcome. Good luck with your exam.

Comment: How do you know that I have exams??

Comment: @MaryStar I assume you do because you came back for this exercise. Furthermore, in my country exams start about now, this strengthens my believe.